# Trying To Recreate a Process in a Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, process-builder, automation

I have a Process that I am trying to recreate in a Flow.

**Problem:** We have a custom Object called BizDW that sort of mimics Account History. We need records for the BizDW Object created when certain fields on a single Account record are updated. If 2 of these fields are updated at once, than 2 BizDW records need to be created.

I am able to make this work in Process Builder, but would like to get this into a Flow since Process Builder is supposed to be going away. Below is a pic my process. It starts when an Account record is created or updated. I'm using the ISCHANGED formula on a few different Account fields to trigger each step. If the certain fields change, the corresponding BidDW record is created.

Does anyone know what I can do to put this into a single Flow? I tried using a decision element, but it will only create 1 record even of multiple trigger fields are changed. I know I can accomplish this by creating multiple flows. But, I'd like to keep this in 1 flow if possible. Is there a way to recreate the "Evaluate The Next Criteria Step" to create another record the same way I can in Process Builder, but in Flow?

Thank you so much for taking the time to look.

[image]

Comment: Your Flow will have three decision elements, whose true path adds a new BizDW record variable to a record collection variable; then you have 1 Create records element to insert the record collection variable

Comment: You might want to add a few screen captures of what your flow does right now so we get an idea of where you're stuck